# Include a line break in algorithmic while maintaining indentation

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, algorithms

I have this code:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
  \hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
    \textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{style=algori}

\begin{document}
    \section{Struttura dati}
    \begin{floatleft}
        \captionof{algorithm}{Leggi file .gpx}\label{getgpx}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                  \State $speed \gets computeSpeed(\linebreak gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_s(q), \linebreak gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_t(q));$
            \end{algorithmic}
    \end{floatleft}
\end{document}
```

This is how code is shown:

[image]

I want the lines `gpx.track....delta_s(q),`,  `gpx.track....delta_t(q),` and `);` to be indented exactly as the beginning of line `27` is. I've tried using the `\indent` command but the indentation space is not the same as in the rest of the document and the final result is chaotic.

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: I have the same problem, and the solution by Werner is too cumbersome to use. So, I start a bounty.

Comment: @BorisBukh: I've added an alternative that might be more suitable and hopefully less cumbersome.

Answer (score 39):

The default indent for each block in the `algorithmic` environment (from the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)) is `\algorithmicindent`. As such, you can place the entire line of code in a top-aligned `\parbox[t]` of adequate width or use the `varwidth` environment from the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth), and indent as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\begin{document}
\section{Struttura dati}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Leggi file .gpx}\label{getgpx}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
      speed~$\gets$~computeSpeed(\par
        \hskip\algorithmicindent gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_s(q),\par
        \hskip\algorithmicindent gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_t(q));
      \end{varwidth}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}​
```

Here is another alternative that could be used instead. It utilized the a modified version of `\Statex`, also supplied by `algorithmicx`. It now takes an optional argument indicating the number of indents to apply to the specific line, without numbering it (default for `\Statex`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\makeatletter
\let\OldStatex\Statex
\renewcommand{\Statex}[1][3]{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{\algorithmicindent}%
  \OldStatex\hskip\dimexpr#1\@tempdima\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Struttura dati}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Leggi file .gpx}\label{getgpx}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State speed~$\gets$~computeSpeed(
    \Statex gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_s(q),
    \Statex[2] gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_t(q));
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

---

Note that I've stripped the unnecessary preamble content from the minimal working example (MWE) posted above. This is encouraged when posting problems/question - something that can compile that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It works. But it's normal that compiler gave me again badbox errror, even if line is perfectly bounded?

Comment: What did you specify as the width `<len>` for your `\parbox{<len>}{...}`? Note that this quantity should be less than what is available on the line.

Comment: @Werner: I'm having a similar issue, but this solution is less than perfect, since you have to add this `parbox` for every line that doesn't fit into the line width. Plus, you have to know the line width to specify for the `parbox` - which may be ok for a piece of code, but not ok for text which needs to be justified.

Comment: @Werner Why not using `\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}` instead of `\parbox`? Of course `\usepackage{varwidth}` is needed.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, I didn't know the original context would be far greater than I had posted, so using `\parbox` sufficed, until now.

Comment: @EyalRozenberg: I've updated my answer to use `varwidth` instead - it allows for a natural-width box up to some maximum (`\linewidth` in this case). That addresses your second concern.

Comment: @Werner: [you rang?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=an_by5r8EUc)

Comment: @EyalRozenberg: I've updated my answer again, now using a modified `\Statex`, which might be more useful. It eliminates the use of `\parbox` or `varwidth`.

Comment: This is much better, thanks! One problem is when applying it to \For loop. It ends with "do". So, it seems that I one needs to define another version of \For (without a do), and then insert \textbf{do}. Similarly for \While. Is there a way to avoid these problems?

Comment: @Werner: I didn't ask the question, I think you meant to @-inform someone else (in case my earlier comment wasn't clear :-) ...)

Comment: Can it be done under an if statement ? , where breaked line ended with `then`

Comment: @alper: Sure; anything's possible. Provide some code on [Pastebin](//pastebin.com) that one can work with, or ask a follow-up question.

Comment: @Werner Thanks, please see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668046/how-can-i-include-a-line-break-for-if-statement-in-algorithm

Answer (score 13):

If all the other solutions seem too complicated, try using a combination of \newline with \hspace*{}:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\section{Struttura dati}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Leggi file .gpx}\label{getgpx}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State speed~$\gets$~computeSpeed(\newline
        \hspace*{5em} gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_s(q), \newline
        \hspace*{5em} gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_t(q));
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This produces
[image]

Answer (score 7):

This is an addition to Werner's answer. As noted in the comments, that solution does not work with `\For` and `\While` loops since they include a "do" at the end. One can define alternative versions of `\For` and `\While` as in the example below

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\StatexIndent}[1][3]{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{\algorithmicindent}%
  \Statex\hskip\dimexpr#1\@tempdima\relax}
\algdef{S}[WHILE]{WhileNoDo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{Cool algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \WhileNoDo{everything is all right, and}
    \StatexIndent[2] the sun is shining bright \algorithmicdo
       \State Sing and dance
    \EndWhile
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I hope it is helpful to someone else too.

Comment: The solutions seems to work, but does not work out of the box with if when `\Else` is used.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with the `If` block. For me, it turned out, that using `\phantom` was the solution. Just insert letters and characters until the indent and the wrapping is OK. Then put `\phantom` before these artificial letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{Demo}{}
\If{This is a very long condition with a long natural text $\mathsf{but\ math\ can\ be\ used,\ too}$ \phantom a \phantom . \phantom . \phantom . and the indent should be right}
\State Statement
\EndIf
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it seems like a huge hack and one would hope for something better. For instance, if the "if" is changed to a different word, then indentation would have to be fixed all over, and this seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, except that my long expression was the condition of an If statement.  I fixed it by using a LaTeX array environment for my expression, the output looks a little strange because it does not look like idomatic pesudocode.

```
\If{$\left(
    \begin{array}{l}
    (current\_context \neq \text{NULL})\, \vee \\
    (MR\_num\_outstanding\_contexts < MR\_max\_contexts) \\
    \end{array}
    \right)$}
```

If the math-style output is acceptable then this is pretty easy.

Comment: A compiled example would be nice.