# Pseudocode overflow out of column

Tags: line-breaking, algorithms, ieeetran, algorithmicx

I am writing pseudocode using the `algorithmicx` package in `IEEEtran` class (double column). My problem is, some of the statement in the code are quite long which I expected to wrap to next line. However, the lines are overflowing out of the margin, something like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Network similarity}
\begin{algorithmic}[2]
\Require{$G\_ref, G\_tar,ref\_community, tar\_community$}
\ForAll{$ref\_node \in G\_ref $}
\ForAll{$tar\_node \in G\_tar$}
\State{ $pair\_sim\_table[ref\_node,tar\_node] \gets Calculate\_similarity(ref\_feature\_vec[ref\_node],tar\_feature\_vec[tar\_node])$}
\EndFor
\EndFor \\
\Return pair\_sim\_table, cluster\_sim
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Since the code associated with the `\State` command is quite long, it overflows out of the margin, instead of wrapping around. Excuse me if this is a trivial question. Any help would be appreciated !

[image: algo]

Comment: You should introduce manual line breaks yourself and correct for the indentation, if needed. See [Include a line break in `algorithmic` while maintaining indentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33979/5764). If such manual intervention is what you're after, then I would consider this a duplicate, since the answer there should solve your problem (using something like `\Statex` or perhaps the [`varwidth` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth)). Give some feedback after investigating.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the link ! The `varwidth` package did it for me. Thanks a lot. Is it required to delete this question (if it is possible ) since the answer to it was actually given in an earlier post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a principal problem in your code is the use of the `$` math-mode delimiters to set text in italics. By doing this, you get very poorly (unkerned) lettering in the words (most notably between "e" and "f", as in "ref"). Worse, in at least one case TeX sees the whole expression as one big in-line math formula and can't figure out (by its own syntax rules) *where* to place a line break; hence the overflow.

I suggest you try the following approach instead, which only uses `$` for explicit math items such as `\in` and `\gets`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Network similarity}
\begin{algorithmic}[2]
\Require{\emph{G\_ref}, \emph{G\_tar}, \emph{ref\_community}, \emph{tar\_community}}
\ForAll{\emph{ref\_node $\in$ G\_ref}}
\ForAll{\emph{tar\_node $\in$ G\_tar}}
\State{\emph{pair\_sim\_table}[\emph{ref\_node},\emph{tar\_node}] $\gets$  
  \emph{Calculate\_similarity}(\emph{ref\_feature\_vec}[\emph{ref\_node}], 
  \emph{tar\_feature\_vec}[\emph{tar\_node}])}
\EndFor
\EndFor \\
\Return \emph{pair\_sim\_table}, \emph{cluster\_sim}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mico: Thanks for the tip ! This has also worked out quite well for me.