# Pseudo-code with algorithmic. Escape and indent a function using varwidth and parbox

Tags: algorithmic, varwidth, parbox

I'm using the algorithmic package to create pseudo-code for my document. One of the algorithms has a few lines that are too long and they go too far to the edge of the page so I wanted to add a breakline in between a function and the second part of the function to indent so that it starts on the same indentation where the function started.

I found this solution here: [Include a line break in algorithmic while maintaining indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33979/include-a-line-break-in-algorithmic-while-maintaining-indentation). And wanted to use the solution using varwidth and parbox. So I did this on my code:

```
\begin{algorithm}[tbp]
\caption{Bla bla}
\label{alg:traintestdeep}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]% 
\Procedure{train\_test}{$train\_features, test\_features, unlabeled\_features$} \label{imgpix}
    \Statex Returns test results of the deep classifier.

    \State $\mathit{ResNet} \gets load()$ \Comment{ResNet50 weights}
    \State $\mathit{Incep} \gets load()$ \Comment{InceptionV3 weights}
    \State $\mathit{Xcep} \gets load()$ \Comment{Xception weights}

    \State \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}

    \State {$res\_features \gets ResNet(train\_features,$\par
    \hskip\algorithmicindent $test\_features,unlabeled\_features)$}

    \State {$inc\_features \gets Incep(train\_features,$\par
    \hskip\algorithmicindent $test\_features,unlabeled\_features)$}

    \State {$xcp\_features \gets Xcep(train\_features,$\par
    \hskip\algorithmicindent $test\_features,unlabeled\_features)$}

    \end{varwidth}

    \State {$all\_features \gets concat(res\_features,inc\_features,xcp\_features)$}

    \If{$save\_features = True$} 
        \State {$savef(all\_features)$}
    \EndIf

    \State {$model \gets create\_model()$} \label{alg:model}

    \If {$training = True$}
        \State {$fitted\_model \gets model.fit(all\_features[train], labels)$} \label{alg:fitmodel1}
        \If {$pseudo = True$} 
            \State \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}

            \State {$newly\_labeled \gets $\par
            \hskip\algorithmicindent $pseudo\_labeling(fitted\_model,all\_features[unlabeled])$} \label{alg:fitmodel2}

            \end{varwidth}

            \State {$fitted\_model \gets fitted\_model.fit(newly\_labeled, labels)$} \label{alg:fitmodel3}
        \EndIf
        \State {$model \gets fitted\_model$}
    \EndIf

    \If {$testing = True$}
        \State {$results \gets fitted\_model(all\_features[test])$}
    \EndIf

    \State\Return $results$

\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

But the result is messy like shown here:

[image]

on lines 6, 7, 8 and 18 that is where I need to escape and indent the line. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `\State` in the `{varwidth}` block. You can change your `{varwidth}` block without `\State`.

```
\State \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}

    {$res\_features \gets ResNet(train\_features,$\par
    \hskip\algorithmicindent $test\_features,unlabeled\_features)$}

     {$inc\_features \gets Incep(train\_features,$\par
    \hskip\algorithmicindent $test\_features,unlabeled\_features)$}

     {$xcp\_features \gets Xcep(train\_features,$\par
    \hskip\algorithmicindent $test\_features,unlabeled\_features)$}

\end{varwidth}
```

[image]