# How to linebreak and keep indentation?

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, indentation, algorithmicx, algpseudocode

While writing down an algorithm, I've come to the following construct:

[image]

There are multiple `for/if/while`'s before this one so it is quite indented.

Example code:

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,algorithmicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\If{true}
\If{$interval.start - error_{early} \leq timestamp + error_{late}$ {\bf and} $timestamp - error_{early} \leq interval.end + error_{late}$}
\State \Return{$false$}
\EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The `If` line is too long an I would like to break the line before or after the `and`. Linebreaking with `\\` does not work.

Comment: From the proposed duplicate, particularly [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33995): `\par\hskip\algorithmicindent {\bf and}` with indentation or `\par\hskip -2mm {\bf and}` without. Note that `\bf` is deprecated, you should use `\textbf{and}` or `{\bfseries and}` (see for example https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2letterfontcmd).

Comment: Thanks, works very nicely. I used multiple `\hskip\algorithmicindent` and then 1mm for what was left.