# How can I include a line break for \If statement in algorithm

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, algorithms

I am trying to apply solution in [Include a line break in algorithmic while maintaining indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33995/127048) for the lines starting with `if`. But `then` does not carried out to breaked line.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\makeatletter
\let\OldStatex\Statex
\renewcommand{\Statex}[1][3]{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{\algorithmicindent}%
  \OldStatex\hskip\dimexpr#1\@tempdima\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Struttura dati}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Leggi file .gpx}\label{getgpx}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
      \If{x=10 \textbf{and}}
      \Statex y=10
    \State speed~$\gets$~computeSpeed(
    \Statex gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_s(q),
    \Statex[2] gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_t(q));
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Wanted output:

```bash
1: if x=10 and 
       y=10  then
2:     speed ← computeSpeed(...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following defines a new if called `\multilineIf` that allows you to specify a stacked set of conditions using a `tabular`-like format (conditions are separated by `\\`). The closing **then** is automatically added to the end of the conditions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\let\OldStatex\Statex
\renewcommand{\Statex}[1][3]{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{\algorithmicindent}%
  \OldStatex\hskip\dimexpr#1\@tempdima\relax}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\stackedconditions}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}}
    #1
  \end{tabular}%
}
\algdef{SE}[IF]{multilineIf}{EndIf}[1]{\algorithmicif\ \stackedconditions{#1\ \algorithmicthen}}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}%

\begin{document}

\section{Struttura dati}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Leggi file .gpx}\label{getgpx}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \multilineIf{%
      $x = 10$ \textbf{and} \\
      $y = 10$}
      \State speed~$\gets$~computeSpeed(
      \Statex gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_s(q),
        \Statex[2] gpx.track(i).segment(j).delta\_t(q));
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The conditions are `l`eft-aligned by default, but you could change this to suit your needs.

The definition of `\multilineIf` via `\algdef` was copied-and-changed from the original `\If` definition with [`algpseudocode.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty).

Comment: I was using `\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}` to prevent `end if` to show up. Is it possible to suppress end if to printed in your solution as well? I have removed `\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif` but now it prints empty-line instead  ; I am sorry I forget to mention this in my original question

Comment: @alper: Add `\algtext*{EndIf}` just after the `\algdef` definition of `multilineIf`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how but worked like magic :)

Comment: @alper: See [`algpseudocode` without end block text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53518/5764).